# Is there a jenkins reporting plugin that works with parallel automation tests with Protractor Cucumber?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, reporting-services, protractor, cucumber

I spent days searching online. So I'm using multiple-cucumber-html-reporter https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin on my local machine for multiple browser testing in parallel. I need this on Jenkins too. Is there a way to set it up in Jenkins or is there a Jenkins plugin out there for multiple browser parallel testing?

I installed Cucumber Reports on Jenkins, but it seems like it's suppose to be used for 1 browser test. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin

Comment: Have you checked [ReportBuilder](https://github.com/rajatthareja/ReportBuilder). Check if you can hook this to your framework.

Comment: ReportBuilder kind of looks like protractor-multiple-cucumber html reporter. Is this a plugin for Jenkins?

Comment: It's not a plugin but you can use this in your framework so that you can generate a consolidated html report and store in jenkins as part of execution.